# C++ to convert minutes and seconds

Tags: c++, converters, minute

I have a C++ code to convert seconds and minutes but it seems like whenever it convert the second, it won't update the minute. How can I fix it?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void Convert(int value, int &hour, int &minute, int &seconds)
{
    hour=value/60;
    minute=value%60;
    seconds=value%60;
}

int main()
{
    int hour;
    int seconds;
    int Seconds_To_Convert = 90;
    int minute;
    int Minutes_To_Convert = 70;

    //calling Convert function
    Convert(Minutes_To_Convert, hour, minute, seconds );

    //compute
    cout<<hour <<" hours and "<<minute<<" minutes "<<"and "<<seconds<<" seconds ";
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Well, your calculation for `minute` and your calculation for `seconds` are identical. So...

Comment: `second = 0;` sounds correct in your case or may be `second = 30;`

Comment: The Minutes_To_Convert and Seconds_To_Convert are user specified, thus its seperated

Comment: @Cael `Seconds_To_Convert` is unused in your code. What is separated from what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like this function should take an `int` number of seconds, then resolve that into hrs + mins + secs.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void Convert(int value, int &hour, int &minute, int &seconds)
{
    hour = value / 3600;           // Hour component
    minute = (value % 3600) / 60;  // Minute component
    seconds = value % 60;          // Second component
}

int main()
{
    int hour;
    int seconds;
    int minute;
    int Seconds_To_Convert = 5432;

    //calling Convert function
    Convert(Seconds_To_Convert, hour, minute, seconds );

    //compute
    cout << hour <<" hours and " << minute << " minutes " << "and " << seconds << " seconds ";
    return 0;
}
```

Output

```
1 hours and 30 minutes and 32 seconds
```

[Working example](http://cpp.sh/42d3)